# Can I use the hierarchyID type with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008

I'm asking since I saw that Entity Framework 4 does not support this usage. Anyone got an answer / a link to one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can write support for it (and any other type from any other DB) by implementing `IUserType`.

Comment: Thanks, taken into consideration.

Comment: You may see a working `IUserType` class here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374904/sql-2008-hierarchyid-support-in-nhibernate/11087277#11087277